# React slick carousel items get blurred

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-slick

I have a carousel that have some card items. but it gets blurred when the carousel animates. I couldn’t find a fix for this. I'm using Next.js with TypeScript.

```
const ref = useRef<any>();

  const settings = {
    arrows: false,
    variableWidth: true,
    infinite: true,
    draggable: true,
    speed: 2000,
    swipe: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    cssEase: 'linear',
  };

 <Slider {...settings} ref={ref}>
    {isLoading
      ? [...Array(9)].map((x, i) => <ExpertCardPlaceholder key={i} />)
      : experts.map(expert => <ExpertCard key={expert.userId} expert={expert} />)}
 </Slider>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can always set useTransforms to false

See reference here:

https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/2531#issuecomment-249303728